# How can I hide and restore only bookmarked lines using notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, bookmarks

I have a document with thousands of lines.  It includes labels by geographic region and random lines from all regions have non-ascii characters present.

I have the regex to remove the non-ascii but it will apply to all lines and I only wish to remove the non-ascii characters from the japanese regions.

My thought was to bookmark all lines with the JPN tag.  Inverse.  Then hide said lines.  Run the regex to clear the non-ascii, then restore the hidden bookmarked lines.

Unfortunately I am stuck on how I can manage the hidden portion.  It seems its possible to manually hide a line with ALT+H, or even a block of lines.  Unfortunately this doesnt help me in my specific case as they arent sorted by region and need to stay that way.  I cant seem to find a way to hide or unhide bookmarked lines en mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml), this regex will match all japanese characters:

```
[　-ヿ一-龥｢-￮]+(?:\h*[　-ヿ一-龥｢-￮]+)*
```

**Explanation:**

```
[　-ヿ一-龥｢-￮]+         # 1 or more any japanese characters
(?:                     # non capture group
  \h*                   # 0 or more horizontal spaces
  [　-ヿ一-龥｢-￮]+       # 1 or more any japanese characters
)*                      # end group, may appear 0 or more times
```

Comment: on the fence about selecting this as the answer.  I probably should as it works as a solution to my problem.  However id love to know if it were possible to blanket hide/unhide bookmarked lines as well for future applications.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @klepp0906: I don't think it's possible to process an action on all lines but bookmarked ones (hide or not).